# playing an audio from a node stream in react-native

Tags: node.js, react-native, audio, stream

I'm working on the backend of an app that should be able to play some audio files it downloads from the server. The audios are being served as static files by nginx.

The app is being developed using react-native. And there are open source audio players out there that can stream an audio file given its url. No problem so far.

But the user should not be able to listen to these audio files outside the app. So what I have in mind, is serving the encryptetd version of these files using nginx.

But in order for this to be useful, the app should be able to play the encrypted files without storing the decrypted version on the device.

This seems to be a problem because all the react-native audio players I can find, either take the path of the audio file on the device or its url on the internet to play it. But I need a player that takes a node stream as input.

So does anyone know of a react-native audio player that takes a node stream as input?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Streaming the audio through some other protocol doesn't protect it in any way.

The only reasonable thing you can do is use DRM, such as with Widevine.  And, keep in mind that this is not fool proof... the audio can be easily recorded later.  There's nothing you can do about this.

Comment: Yeah, but that would be harder than just copying a bunch of audio files. Is there any drm module for react-native that can play encrypted files directly?